# Programmatically change a Storyboard's Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am developing a game, and I have been saving level design for the end. Anyway, I am here now and running into issues. I would like to use the same storyboard for all of the levels, but just change the class of the storyboard to a different view controller. I am assuming that having 50+ storyboards in your project is not a good thing, correct me if I am wrong.

Right now this is the "sample" code I have, just to give an idea of what I want to do.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    nextViewConroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("levelStoryboard")
    storyboard.class = "Level" + String(currentLevel) + "Controller" // Purely concept code - does not work.
    presentViewController(nextViewConroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here or what you think changing the "class of the storyboard" would mean. Why do you think you need some 50+ view controllers? What is different about them and what are you trying to repeat? Do they all share the same view, in which case why do you need so many controllers?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, I think you don't need a new class for each level, you rather need a new instance of your view controller.

Comment: All of the levels have different features, but can use the same storyboard. So I have 50 view controllers, and Id like the custom class found in the identity inspector to change to the corresponding level.

Answer (score 2):

Good programmers will reuse things as much as possible. If your levels are basically the same, with just a few differences in view structure/logic, then I recommend making one storyboard pointing to one view controller say, "LevelViewController". You could then have some config function that configures this controller for a specific level, and a great place to do that is in prepareForSegue:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    nextViewConroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("levelStoryboard") as! LevelViewController
     nextviewcontroller.configureForLevel(2)

}
```

But, if you must use a different view controller because every level is totally different, just pass the identifier of the new class you want to use:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
nextViewConroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("level_0") as! Level0ViewController
```

Remember that instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: looks in your storyboard file to see if you have a view controller object with that identifier, and returns it. This returned view controller will also be the same class you specify in the custom class section of the identity inspector.

Whichever technique you use, Make sure you set the custom class in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common UI that has varying logic depending on some condition, you could separate the varying logic in as many classes as needed and merely use the IB's view controller as a channel to the common user interface elements.   The view controller class you specify in IB would simply have the IBOutlets and IBActions plus a variable with the appropriate instance of the "logic" class.  Upon initialization, the view controller would only have to instantiate the appropriate type for the logic class (a good place to use a factory pattern) and link the outlets to the object or merely act as a delegate.